# Java enum with no instances

Tags: java, enums, rx-java, rx-javafx

In RXJava [1] there is an enum [2] defined as

```
public enum JavaFxObservable {
    ; // no instances


    public static void staticMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What's the purpose this technique using a enum with no instances? Why not use a standard class?

---

- [1] https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava
- [2] https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX/blob/0.x/src/main/java/rx/observables/JavaFxObservable.java

Comment: Not sure really, but i think it might be clean way to prevent from extending or creating instance

Comment: This "class" is just a repository of static functions (and/or constants). An enum cannot be extended, is a final class. The alternative would be to make a final or abstract class with a private constructor. Which is more verbose. BTW enum is also used for a singleton, with concurrency safe initialisation.

Comment: "Why not use a standard class?" can you give an example of how such a standard class would be better/simpler?

Comment: Saves you from writing a `private` constructor and marking the class `final`. e.g. This can be used to create helper classes which only contain static methods without being instantiable (And it also reduces the amount  boilerplate code that you'd normally write)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the purpose this technique using a enum with no instances?

You are defining, in the simplest way, that this is a class which has no instances, i.e. it is utility class.

> Why not use a standard class?

An `enum` is a class. It is also final with a private constructor. You could write

```
public final class JavaFxObservable {
    private JavaFxObservable() {
        throw new Error("Cannot create an instance of JavaFxObservable");
    }
}
```

But this is more verbose and error prone. e.g. I have seen this in real code

```
public final class Util {
    private Util() {
    }

    static void someMethod() { }

    static class DoesSomething {
         void method() {
             // WAT!? we can still create this utility class
             // when we wrote more code, but it's not as good.
             new Util().someMethod(); 
         }
    }
}
```

The comments are mine. ;)